# Send multiple array to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two arrays, first is an array with its data is declared  on controller and the second is an array from a query operation. Both of them are not related to other. Lets name them $array1 and  $array2. Below is my controller

```
$array1['status'] = 'admin';
$array1['name'] = 'John';

$this->load->model('mymodel');
$array2 = $this->mymodel->get_all_row();

$this->load->view('my_view', $array1, $array2);
```

Lets say the `$array2` have 3 indexes `id`, `name`, `price`.

Need some helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the variable in your view as you pass it. Using array($var1,$var2); is valid but probably not what you wanted to achieve.
See [Views](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) for detailed documentation how to access variables passed to a view.

Try

```
$data = $var1 + $var2;
```

or

```
$data = array_merge($var1, $var2);
```

Comment: hello, kindly, how do I do a foreach just and only $array1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The view accepts only two parameters.

> Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or
>   an object in the second parameter of the view loading method. Here is
>   an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
        'title' => 'My Title',
        'heading' => 'My Heading',
        'message' => 'My Message'
);

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

**Third Parameter of View**

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the method so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it
>   to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in
>   some way. If you set the parameter to TRUE (boolean) it will return
>   data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
>   Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', TRUE);
```

So, bottom line is that you have to send one array. Now if you wanna pass data of two array, you should merge these arrays into and then pass merged array.

```
$merged_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$this->load->view('my_view', $merged_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass two arrays to your view, you need to convert the data array to a two-dimensional array.
For example, you have two arrays with the following names and contents:

```
[A1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => '1'
        [Name] => 'Jon'
    )

[A2] => Array
    (
        [Tell] => '123456'
        [Address] => 'Somware'
    )
```

To pass two arrays, place them in the data array with different keys

```
$data['A1']=$A1;
$data['A2']=$A2;
```

Result:

```
[data] => Array
(
    [A1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => '1'
            [Name] => 'Jon'
        )

    [A2] => Array
        (
            [Tell] => '123456'
            [Address] => 'Somware'
        )
)
```

and use in view like this:

```
echo $A1['ID'];
echo $A1['Name'];
echo $A2['Tell'];
echo $A2['Address'];
```